# The system has detected a possible attempt to compromise security

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

We have two separate Active Directory domains that have a trust relationship.  When I access a network share on the other machine I am prompted for a username and password even though I am logged on as a user that has permissions to the share.  Also the dialog has the following message at the bottom:

“The system has detected a possible attempt to compromise security”

This is causing serious problems with one of the services we are running.  Is this behaviour expected?  I would not expect to have to re-enter my credentials as these should be passed-through and this is causing issues with programmatic access to the network share.  Does anyone have any suggestions to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: You're correct that you should not have to reenter your credentials in a properly-configured trust. When did this start happening? Can you click the 'Validate' button in the properties of the trust, and does it successfully validate?

Comment: Sorry, the powers that be will not let me press the validate button for fear of it causes issues (frustrating I know).  Is there anything else you can suggest to help diagnose this issue.

Comment: Check and see what the machine getting the error has their DNS server(s) set to.  Make sure it is one of the internal AD DNS servers and not something else like a router or external DNS server.

Comment: @DanRyan Uh, validating a trust will not cause any 'issues.' If you don't have the power to validate the trust, then have your sysadmin come talk to us.

Answer (score 3):

What happens in the background when a user in one forest needs access to a resource in a remote trusting domain is this:

- The client contacts a KDC in its own domain
- The KDC supplies the client with a what is known as a referral ticket for the remote domain
- The client sends the referral ticket to a KDC in the trusting forest
- The trusting KDC recognizes the validity and authenticity of the referral ticket
- A service ticket is granted to the user for the service in the remote domain

This process is known as [Referral Processing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_trust_how_fogn).

Without having tested any of the following further, but based on the following KB article: [You receive a "The system has detected a possible attempt to compromise security" error message when you try to include security settings for a user from different domain in a local domain folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938457), I suspect that the remote server is trying to validate the authenticity of the trusted user on it's own.

If the server in the trusting domain can not contact any Domain Controllers in the trusted domain on tcp/88, the validation process will surely fail, and you get that warning.

Check perimeter firewalls between the two domains and see if any traffic towards port 88 is getting dropped

Comment: Thanks for the information, hopefully it will convince the operations team that the trust relationship is not fully set-up correctly (which they are currently refusing to acknowledge).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to a client of mine after taking them over from another technician. Tracked the issue down to issues with DNS servers not allowing local access (8.8.8.8 only server listed on NIC), so took a look at DHCP settings which were on the router. Found the issue there, so migrated DHCP to their single server where it should have been and configured the DNS setting in DHCP to use the Domain Controller's DNS server as primary. Ran an `ipconfig /renew` and logoff to reconnect to the server properly. Problem solved.